# GWT setWidth and Internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-8

I've created a custom widget, which uses a bunch of floated divisions, I'm having a issue with internet explorer though. After playing around a bit, I found that the problem was with setting inline css.

I have a class extending ComplexPanel, which sets the element to a division, and offers a bunch of helper functions to set various inline CSS.

If I add say, 3 divisions using this DIV wrapper class, which all are being floated left, and set to 100px using inline css (set with getElement().getStyle().setProperty()), then they act odd in IE8. (it works fine in IE9).

Basically, none of the inline CSS is being picked up. Using the developer tools shows the CSS is there, but its not being applied. If I disable the float (or width for that matter) and enable it again, using the developer tools, the inline CSS is picked up and it works as intended.

So, how can I inform IE8 that it needs to re-interpret inline CSS on dynamically generated elements?

Comment: can u give me a test case or maybe code of what you have done , because in your question its NOT specified what exactly is happening

also try using display:inline-block; and try seeing the width of the div :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had problems using setProperty()... in ie8. So, avoid it.

Try using one of predefined methods in Style.

Try using getElement().getStyle().setFloat(Float.Left).
and getElement().getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PX).